# Wildcard integer in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Not getting the desired result:

```
Select Where DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%[0-9] PF %'
```

I am looking to pull all Description where any number is folowed by PF.

So for example "2 PF "

Example of data that should be returned in the query:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pattern matching with regex.

```
WHERE DESCRIPTION ~ '\d\sPF'
```

If `PF` needs to be matched regardless of lower or upper case, use

```
WHERE DESCRIPTION ~* '\d\sPF'
```

- `\d` matches `0-9`.
- `\s` is for a space character.
- `PF` is what you need the number to be followed by.

[**`Read about pattern matching in Postgres here`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

Edit: Based on OP's comment that he is using Redshift,

```
WHERE DESCRIPTION SIMILAR TO '%[0-9] PF %'
```

Comment: What does the .*$ after PF indicate?  What about the s before PF?  And why doesn't the solution above work?  Is there nothing simpler?

Comment: I can confirm the above did not return the desired result that would be returned from Select Where DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%[0-9] PF %'

Comment: It is huge (TBs).  Select Where DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%[0-9] PF %' use to work, probably on SQL Server.  Is there an equivalent in postgresql without using regex?

Comment: should there be a mandatory space between the number and PF or is it optional?

Comment: hI @vkp.  The result doesn't match.  It returns "FOODSPflugerville TX" which doesn't match '%[0-9] PF %'

Comment: Hi @vkp I just tried running your solution again, and it is returning values like "AUDIBLE             888-283-505 DSPFLI31ZHW AUDIO BOOKS" but not the values in the image I posted in the original question, which are also in the data.

Comment: i really don;t understand..can you show the actual query being used?

Comment: I used select WHERE DESCRIPTION ~* '\d\sPF' exactly.  It doesn't return the rows highlighted in red above

Comment: don't you have a `from ..` in the query? and which version of postgres are you on?

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the from, assumed it's not relevant?  I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2, which is the only choice for Amazon Redshift.

Comment: so are you using **amazon-redshift** and not **postgres**?

Comment: No I am using amazon redshift which uses PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Comment: see the edit..that is the problem when you tag the incorrect database..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ... WHERE btrim(description) ILIKE '<what>_<ever>';
```

... should do the job. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-binarystring.html